# How to implement operator>>(std::istream&, std::array<char, N>&)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream, istream

I would like a generic, fully compliant istream "extraction operator" like this:

```
template <typename CharT, size_t N, class Traits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& operator>>(
    std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& in,
    std::array<CharT, N>& out)
{
    std::basic_string<CharT, Traits> buf; // this is not great
    in >> buf;
    if (buf.size() >= N) {
        in.setstate(std::ios::failbit); // is this the right thing to do?
        out[0] = 0;
    } else {
        std::copy(buf.begin(), buf.end(), out.data());
        out[buf.size()] = 0;
    }

    return in;
}
```

But this allocates and copies memory unnecessarily.  I'd like to avoid that.  But I also want to keep the full functionality including proper whitespace and support for `std::noskipws`, etc.  Using Boost would be OK if it's much easier.

Comment: I am sure you must have found something problematic with the approach of just reading single character at a time and then maintaining a count as well to check the overflow.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think you should specify the exact behavior you want with some edge-case examples, e.g. `" a b c"`, `"  abc   "`.

Comment: @Holt: I want the exact same behavior as if using `std::string` instead of `std::array<char, N>`, with the one addition of setting failure if the string doesn't fit inside N including a null terminator.  The rest of the behavior and all edge cases should be handled the same as a regular C++ string.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer but too big for a comment:

Overloading an operator whose only operands are in `namespace std` will lead to trouble. This is because of two-phase lookup, any other custom `operator>>` will hide your one, [see example](https://godbolt.org/g/g8wxFA).

Normally this issue is avoided by defining the overloaded operator in the same namespace as one of the operands , so that argument-dependent lookup always finds the operator. (ADL still searches up the enclosing namespaces even if a nearer namespace had the name).

However that solution is not available to you, as it is [undefined behaviour to add your own functions to `namespace std`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

I'm not sure what the preferred workaround is to this problem. If you were hoping to have this function found by generic template code using `>>` on template arguments, you'll need to explicitly make your overload visible, with a `using ::operator>>;` inside the same function invoking the operator. Or perhaps more tidily, `using mystuff::operator>>` where you put your stuff in its own namespace.

Comment: Ouch!  Well, in my particular case I am willing and able to use a typedef or wrapper class for `std::array` in my own namespace.  So I guess I can get around this problem, but it's a doozy so thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
template <typename CharT, size_t N, class Traits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& operator>>(
    std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& in,
    std::array<CharT, N>& out)
{
    in >> std::setw(N) >> out.data();
    if (!in.eof() && !std::isspace((CharT)in.peek(), in.getloc())) {
        out[0] = 0;
        in.setstate(in.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return in;
}
```

As far as I can tell, it behaves like your version with `std::basic_string` except that it never reads more than `N - 1` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#include <array>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename CharT, size_t N, class Traits>
std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& operator>>(
    std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& in,
    std::array<CharT, N>& out)
{
    auto first = out.begin();
    auto last = out.end();
    while (first != last and in)
    {
        in >> *first++;
    }
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream ss { "a cd" };
    ss >> std::noskipws;

    std::array<char, 4> a;
    ss >> a;

    for (char c : a) {
        std::cout << "[" << c << "]\n";
    }
}
```

results:

```
[a]
[ ]
[c]
[d]
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Can you make it do null termination, including placing a zero as the very first character if the input stream is empty or failed?

Comment: There is a significant bug here: it doesn't stop when it encounters whitespace (without noskipws).  The regular `std::string` operator does, and this should too.

Comment: @JohnZwinck when you say "bug", this implies that you had some defined behaviour in mind when these conditions were encountered. I was not aware of these requirements when writing this code (you see the perennial problem between users and implementors?). 
If you state your requirements formally, I could build a test suite to check against them and then iterate this code accordingly until we had a pass.
It all begins with knowing and stating exactly what behaviour you want.